# Turning a subalgebra into an ideal by changing the algebra it is contained in

Tags: ideals, algebras

Let $B$ be an (not necessarily unital) algebra and $A \subseteq B$ a subalgebra. Is there some sort of quotient $C$ of $B$ (or any other interesting construction not necessarily found by taking quotients, but with perhaps some nice universal property, while being as similar to $B$ as possible) such $A$ is still contained in $C$, but $A$ is, further, an ideal of $C$?

Comment: As Mariano says, $A$ contains the unit, so any ideal containing $A$ (in $B$ or any quotient of it) is the unit ideal.

Comment: Hmm, by algebras I was actually thinking more about not necessarily unital ones, and whose subalgebras do not necessarily need to have the same unit. So there could still be some algebra containing $A$ as a non-trivial ideal. I am going to update the question to make this more clear. Does the idealizer construction work in this non-unital case? It seems to me that it does.